# How to generate HHP file from CHM file

Tags: chm

When I decompile my CHM file use microsoft html help workshop. It generates HHC,HHK and bunch of HTML files but no HHP file. When I create an HHP file using new project option and then compile it to create another CHM file. Now these two CMH files are not of same size and they behave differently. Am I missing something here? I am simply decompiling and re-compiling the same CHM file but the result is different.

Answer (score 1):

Well, logic dictates then that the original HHP file was different :-) Though of course workshop versioning might also be related.

As far as I know decompiling HTML is not entirely reversable, and I also doubt it takes proper care of workshop versioning. It's considered mainly a one way conversion, not a way to archive data reliably.